# Coalescing Flux Actions

Tags: reactjs, architecture, frontend, flux

This is a detailed Flux Architecture question.

Say I have a resource that gets asynchronously prepared. Let's take User Data as an example.

There are multiple different ways to get this user data - in our example it may be that it requires a few different subsequent queries to generate from the server or is stored locally as a whole.

Case 1:
User data needs sequential steps. Fire USER_DATA_1_SUCESS, USER_DATA_2_SUCCESS. Other stores listen for USER_DATA_2_SUCCESS.

Case 2:
User Data is locally available as a whole. Fire a USER_DATA_READY action.

I'm trying to figure out how to go from a linear state completion (USER_DATA_2_SUCESS) to a resource ready event (USER_DATA_READY) in the stores. I can't call USER_DATA_READY directly from the stores - I get a can't call action in the middle of dispatch error. At the same time I want granularity - I want to control the different stages of putting the data together.

I'd like to have one way to condense these calls with good design. The option I can think of is:

Add a convenience 'Ready' function in a client class that is visible to the store. Call it with a tiny timeout in the stores callback for USER_DATA_2_SUCCESS.

Can anyone suggest a better flow?

Comment: What are the circumstances of data being ready locally? Do you mean you've done the fetches previously and are navigating back to a view where that data, already in memory will be used?

Comment: I decided to cache user info to avoid a network request. Say it's on app initialize to simplify the question.

Comment: Ah in that case I highly recommend implementing your cache at the action layer, so that you just have one ...FETCH-SUCCESS event, whether that is dispatched on the tail of an actual async fetch or a sync cache hit. Stores then hydrate the same either way, and so on.